# java email insert parameter values into subject and message

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

i need some help to a quite common issue i guess. I am using a .properties file for defining some static texts in my java application. In this .properties file i have define a subject and a message for an email that i would like to send in a specific case. So here is the relevant part of my application.properties file:

```
fail_msgToAddress = xxxx@yyyy.zzz
fail_msgSubject = [FAIL TO PROCESS EXAM] Study: %s for Patient %s could not be processed due to invalid examination codes
fail_msgText = <p>Case: %s, for patient: %s, failed to be processed since it seemed not to correspond to a valid examination type!</p><p> Please communicate with Npap lab for specific instructions</p>
```

In my code i would like to pass two parameters: a study id and a patient name to email subject and message. So i have set some methods to fetch this info from my properties file and i am trying to use String.format method to insert some parameter values into the text:

```
....
GlobalConfig cfg = new GlobalConfig();
String emailAddr = cfg.failMsgToAddress();
String emailSubj = cfg.failMsgSubject();
String emailTxt = cfg.failMsgText();
...
try {
    Notifier ntf = new Notifier();
    emailSubj = String.format("[FAIL TO PROCESS EXAM] Study: %s for Patient %s could not be processed due to invalid examination codes", d, dcSerMeta.getAnonymizationData(d).getPatientName());
    emailTxt = String.format(emailTxt, d, dcSerMeta.getAnonymizationData(d).getPatientName());
    ntf.sendMail(emailAddr, emailSubj, emailTxt);
    ....
}
```

where Notifier is my mail wrapper class. Its sendMail method is a classical implementation for sending html email.

I am using the common javax.mail library and Notifier.sendMail method is:

```
public boolean sendMail(String msgToAddress, String msgSubject, String msgText) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    boolean result = false;

    GlobalConfig cfg = new GlobalConfig();

    smtpServer = cfg.getSmtpServer();
    smtpPort = Integer.parseInt(cfg.getSmtpPort());
    smtpUser = cfg.getSmtpUsername();
    smtpPassword = cfg.getSmtpPassword();
    emailSender = cfg.getSmtpSender();
    smtpProtocol = cfg.getSmtpProtocol();

    smtpSecure = ("0".equals(cfg.getSmtpSecure())) ? "false" : "true";

    log.info("###SMTP server: " + smtpServer + ", SMTP port: " + smtpPort + ", SMTP username: " + smtpUser + ", SMTP password: " + smtpPassword + ", email Sender: " + emailSender + ", smtpSecure: " + smtpSecure + ", smtpProtocol: " + smtpProtocol);
    Properties props = new Properties();

    MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory(); socketFactory.setTrustedHosts(new String[] { smtpServer });
    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);

    if("true".equals(smtpSecure)) {

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", smtpProtocol);
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", smtpServer);
        props.put("mail.smtps.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory", socketFactory);

    } else {

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", smtpProtocol);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");            
        props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory", socketFactory);
    }

    Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();

    javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props, auth);

    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Transport transport;
        try {
            transport = mailSession.getTransport();
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                try {
                    message.setSubject(msgSubject);
                    //message.setContent(msgText, "text/plain");
            message.setContent(msgText, "text/html" );
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailSender));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(msgToAddress));

        transport.connect();
                transport.sendMessage(message,
                    message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                transport.close();
                result = true;
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                 
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
   }
```

However the String.format method do not seem to work and when i am receiving the email i just get the '%s' instead of the actual parameter values! What am i missing?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  It should be easy to isolate the String.format part into a trivial test program for debugging.  Have you tried that?

Comment: If this is part of larger work, please consider using a template based approach(http://freemarker.org/ or any other)

Comment: What's the result of System.out.println(emailSubj);?